# How do I set up a DNS server with some of my private iP targets (aka "customized hosts")

Tags: dns

Well, as in the biggest communism country on this planet, you have to "bypass" some block/censorship for some very famous websites. Youtube, Google, Facebook..

I have found a way to bypass via customized hosts but that's very annoying to set up hosts files in all my computers and update them from time to time.

So I am thinking of building up my own DNS server that I can easily update new hosts records to it.

Is there any tutorial that meets my requirements?

update:

I want to use my Linode server in US. info about my server:

`Linux version 2.6.18.8-x86_64-linode10 (root@build.linode.com) (gcc version 4.3.3 (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) ) #1 SMP Tue Nov 10 16:29:17 UTC 2009`

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a NAS by any chance?  What router and operating systems do you use?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials that meet this broad request - can you be more specific or advise things that haven't worked

Comment: @Paul what is "NAS"?

Comment: @ekaj with a customized hosts file, I can access many sites!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.howtoforge.com/two_in_one_dns_bind9_views is a good tutorial on how to configure bind to have a front and rear facing DNS, assuming all the people you want to use your dns would be internal as I assume external users would put you at more risk than you want.

I might add that this might be in violation of http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy particularly "Illegal Use. Stack Exchange may not be used for illegal purposes " which this would most likely fall under.

That said I dislike censorship, and feel that it's against what this site stands for so more power to you.

Comment: Well, thanks very much and nice point. I am also very eager to know how will StackOverflow determine whether this did violated their policy!